# Docker, How to replace capistrano tasks in docker

Tags: docker, ansible, capistrano, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize my production rails application.

Currently app is configured using Ansible and deployed using capistrano.

I researched for different docker deployment strategy's and thought of getting rid of capistrano in docker and will be using docker with docker-compose

I am writing dockerfile to configure and deploy app, but it is somewhat complex to deploy app similar to capistrano as deploy.rb is using few rake tasks to setup predeployment tasks like creating directories setting app name and fetching few variables.

How can I duplicate cap tasks in dockerfile or is there a way to use current cap rake tasks in docker file or running docker container ?

Answer (score 1):

Now is a good time to step back and consider if the benefits of Docker outweigh the added complexity, for your situation.  Assuming it is, here are a few suggestions on how to make these components work together better.

While Ansible is a configuration management system, it's also designed for orchestration (that is, running commands across a series of remote machines).  This has some cross-over with Capistrano, and as such, you may find it useful to port your Capistrano tasks to Ansible and eliminate a tool (and thus complexity) from your stack.  This would likely come about from creating a `deploy.yaml` playbook that you run to deploy your application.

Docker also overlaps responsibilities with Ansible, but in a different area, configuration.  Any part of your system configuration that's necessary for the app can be configured inside the container using the Dockerfile, rather than on a system-wide level using Ansible.

If you have rake tasks that set up the application environment, you can put them in a `RUN` command in the Dockerfile.  Keep in mind, however, that these will only be executed when you *build* the image, not when you *run* it.

Generally speaking, I view it this way:  Docker sets up a container that has everything required to run one piece of your app (including a specific checkout of your code).  Ansible configures the environment in which you run the containers and manages all the work to update them and put them in the right places.

Comment: Yes you are right that this will be fetched only while building dockerfile, but my pain right now is to get the rake tasks from capistrano working on container or should I simply convert those in shell script and invoke them from dockerfile ? btw Thanks for your detailed explanation, But I will use Ansible to only provision the containers.

Comment: It depends on what your Cap commands are doing.  If they already operate only on the local machine, then you can simply `RUN` them in the dockerfile.  If they're designed to operate on remote hosts, then you'll have to do a bit of work to get your docker containers accessible via a standard orchestration method like ssh, or rewrite them to only operate on a local machine.